# Required: no arguments, despite having arguments?

Tags: java, arrays, custom-data-type

MealDataTotal.java:25: error: constructor MealData in class MealData cannot be applied to given types;
        new MealData("Burger", 5.99, 650.0),
        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
class MealData
{
  public String name;
  public double price;
  public double calories;

  String MealData (String n,double p,double c)
  {
    name = n;
    price = p;
    calories = c;

    String summaryString;

    summaryString = name + ", $" + Double.toString(price) + ", " + Double.toString(calories) + " calories";
    return summaryString;
  }
}

public class MealDataTotal extends MealData
{

    MealData[] MainCourses = new MealData[] 
    {
        new MealData("Burger", 5.99, 650.0),
        new MealData("Sandwich", 3.99, 450.0f),
        new MealData("Mac 'n Cheese", 4.99, 500.0)
    };

    public static void main(String []args)
    {

        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Read more about constructor and their return types. You will have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A construct does have a return, it returns the instance of the class, this is why you should not declare the return type.

If you want to convert your instance to a String in a custom way override the `toString` method.